# Jquery not always showing Json Response

Tags: jquery, json

. . . .
The problem I am facing regarding the below code is that the

```
$("#message").html(output);
```

line does not always display the message, I check the json response in firebug console and I am always receiving the correct response. But sometimes it shows, sometimes it does not. I really cant figure out whats the problem

Here is the code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="auction_form">
```

and it has two buttons

```
<input type="submit" id="add_auction" class="btn btn-success" value="Add Auction">

<input type="submit" id="update_auction" class="btn btn-success" value="Update Auction">
```

Update auction is hidden by default via jquery. The buttons toggle when user tries to edit

Following is the code for their click event

```
$(":submit").click(function(e) {
    action = $(this).val();
    $(".text-danger").remove();
    data = $("#auction_form").serializeArray();     
    switch(action)
    {
        case "Add Auction":
            url = "<?php echo(base_url()); ?>admin/auctions/auction_add/";
        break;

        case "Update Auction":
            url = "<?php echo(base_url()); ?>admin/auctions/auction_update/";
        break;
    }
    $.post(
        url,
        data, 
        function(response){
            process_ajax_response(response);
        }

    );  
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

and the process_ajax_response function

```
function process_ajax_response(response){
    error = false;
    result = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(result.hasOwnProperty('success')){
        output = "<span class='text-success bg-info'>" + result['success'] + "</span>";
        //alert("success - " + output);
    }
    else if(result.hasOwnProperty('error')){
        //alert("ss");
        error = true;
        output = "<span class='text-danger bg-info'>" + result['error'] + "</span>";

        if(result.hasOwnProperty('errors')){
            //works in case of update
            output = "";
            $("#auction_name").after(result['errors']['auction_name']);
            $("#short_name").after(result['errors']['short_name']);
            $("#code").after(result['errors']['code']);
            $("#country").after(result['errors']['country']);
            $("#auction_date").next().after(result['errors']['auction_date']);
            $("#status").next().after(result['errors']['status']);
        }                   
    }
    //alert("SS - " + output);
    $("#message").html(output);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#message").fadeOut(1000);

        if(!error){
            window.location.href = current_url;

        }

    }, 1000);       
}
```

EDIT:
Ok I have been able to track something. When I get an error msg via json response, I simply display it and it gets displayed properly, and then afterwards msg is not displayed again, until I **REFRESH the page**

Comment: Is there an error with the response? Add an error handler to the Ajax call. My guess is there is a bug with what is being returned in certain cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it and I am sure you all are going to LOL.

First time when I used the form, I get the json response and it gets displayed in the message div and then I fadeOut the div. If the message was for some error, I do nothing(hence the page does not get refreshed), where as when the json response was of a successful operation, the page reloads and next time when I show the message, it gets displayed.

So the problem was that when I fadeOut the div and again sets a message in it, it does not show up as it was hidden :D.

Really sorry for bothering you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an error handler and see what the error is

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: process_ajax_response,
  error : function () {
    console.log("ERROR", arguments);
  }//,
  //dataType: dataType
});
```

Also there should be no need to parse the response to JSON, set the dataType correctly and jQuery will do it for you.

Comment: not working. when I first time click the add button, the msg is displayed, but if I click immediately after that, it just doesnt

Comment: What message is displayed and what is not? Not clear what you are talking about. ARe there errors in the console when it does not work?

Comment: $("#message").html(output);

Comment: well does it go into the `if` or `else if`, add an else `{ alert("whoops"); }` and see if it triggered. Also if it goes into the "errors" it wipes out the output...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to both POST and receive JSON data through AJAX, you should add contentType and dataType to your AJAX call.

```
contentType: "application/json",
datatype : "application/json",
```

As you are not setting contentType, you should be POSTing the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, as I do not see the code called at the url you are passing, I can not say which format you need, but if you want your backend to receive JSON, you should set contentType! As it stands now you are neither POSTing JSON, nor converting your data to JSON properly.

To ensure the data being sent is the proper format I would suggest adding [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
tempD = $("#auction_form").serializeArray();     
data: JSON.stringify(tempD),
```

Comment: at backend I am simply receiving data in post array the response from server side is in json, the problem is that everything else is working fine, even the window.location.href works accordingly when there is no error, its just that the message does not show up. when I add an alert to check the output on client side, the message also starts showing

Comment: Add the correct datatype depending on your data format and add error handling to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: when I first time click the add button, the msg is displayed, but if I click immediately after that, it just doesnt

Answer (score 0):

The intermittent problems are the biggest pains.

Looking at your code, I see that you aren't handling the final "ELSE" of the testing you're doing.

I suggest setting the variables error, result, and output as local variables such as this:

```
var error, result, output = 'Uh oh';
```

The way you're doing it, they are global variables on the window object which is generally frowned upon.

You perform an "if success" followed by an "else if error", but you don't have a final "else" in case there was a third possibility. Perhaps your data is guaranteed to be either one or the other. In my experience, it's ALWAYS best to provide for the final ELSE.

By assigning a default value of 'uh oh' to the output, you'll at least know when/if you ever encountered this third possibility.

You could also just provide for a final else that says something like:

```
else
{   output = 'Reached an unexpected point!<br/>' + JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Then, you'll at least have better visibility into what's going on.

Good Luck!

Comment: else has done nothing. when I first time click the add button, the msg is displayed, but if I click immediately after that, it just doesnt